# No class definition error with IOS driver creation

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, appium

I am getting a NoClassDefFound error for org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonToWebElementConverter when trying to run some code to set up an IOSDriver for use with Appium.  So far all I am trying to do is set up capabilities and open a driver.  However the error occurs on the driver initialization line.

So far I have tried to import org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonToWebElementConverter into the class but still get the same error.  My Eclipse is pointing to the right JDK and Java is installed properly.  I believe I have all dependencies as well.

Dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
<artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
<version>4.1.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>io.appium</groupId>
<artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
<version>7.6.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>com.github.appium</groupId>
<artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
<version>7.6.0</version>
</dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Driver I am trying to set up.

```
        try {
        IOSDriver driver = new IOSDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub"),capabilites);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Resulting Error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/remote/internal/JsonToWebElementConverter
```

at appiumtests.BaseIOTest.main(BaseIOTest.java:31)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.JsonToWebElementConverter
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
... 1 more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an issue with selenium dependency.

Appium 7.6 uses selenium version `3.141.59`, and you've added selenium `4.1.1`, so they are not compatible.

1 Try to remove selenium dependency from the pom.

2 Leave only

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
    <version>7.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

for appium java client.

Comment: exactly the fix.  thank you.